Multiple Webpack bundles cause Bootstrap script to not work
I got this setup:
core.js
import * as bootstrap from 'bootstrap';
import { Popover } from 'bootstrap';
//...code doing some stuff with Popover

someFancyPlugin.js
import { Popover } from 'bootstrap';
//...code doing some different stuff with Popover

Using Webpack, I am bundling both js files separately and are including them in my HTML:
<script src="/build/core.js" defer></script>
<script src="/build/someFancyPlugin.js" defer></script>
    

The odd thing is, the bootstrap js code (e.g. to trigger a dropdown) does NOT work if both files contain import { Popover } from 'bootstrap';. It only works, when I comment out one of the import { Popover } from 'bootstrap'; statements.
This is so confusing, how can I fix it?

Please don't tag your titles. See [ask].

So the solution I found is to define bootstrap as a Webpack external: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/
That way it won't be packaged using Webpack but has to be added manually.
I am working on a project using Symfony/Webpack Encore, so I followed this instruction:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/advanced-config.html#excluding-some-dependencies-from-output-bundles
Essentially this leads to this code:
In webpack.config.js
Encore.addExternals({
   bootstrap: 'bootstrap'
})

Encore.addPlugin(new CopyWebpackPlugin({
        patterns: [
            { from: './node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js', to: 'bootstrap.bundle.min.js' }
        ]
    }))

In the global template
 <script src="{{ asset('build/bootstrap.bundle.min.js') }}"></script>

Alternative would be to not copy the bootstrap.bundle.min.js to the build folder but to include it from a CDN.
